# POSIX Shared Memory writing/reading

Tags: c++, posix, shared-memory

I'm going over the POSIX shared memory section of this text book. I couldn't get the code from the book to compile until I made a few changes. I understand the idea of shared memory and how to open it, but I'm still confused on the read/write. The text book code showed a hello world string example, but I'm not sure how to apply it to ints, arrays, structs etc. Here is the text book code I'm working with. Here is the write.

```
const int SIZE = 4096;
const char *name = "OS";
const char *message_0 = "Hello";
const char *message_1 = "World!";

int shm_fd;
void *ptr;

shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

//sprintf(ptr, "%s", message_0); //non working text book code
sprintf((char*)ptr, "%s", message_0); //my change to get it to work
ptr += strlen(message_0);
//sprintf(ptr, "%s", message_1);
sprintf((char*)ptr, "%s", message_1);
ptr += strlen(message_1);
```

And here is the read.

```
    const int SIZE = 4096;
    const char *name = "OS";
    int shm_fd;
    void *ptr;

    shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_RDONLY, 0666);
    ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

    printf("%s", (char*)ptr);
    shm_unlink(name);
```

I tried changing this to write/read ints, but I couldn't get it to work. I was under the impression that I should be able to do something for ints like:

```
*ptr = 2;
ptr++;
```

But, I couldn't get that, or any other way I tried to work. Can anyone explain it better? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast the mmap result to int* or double* or whatever you like. One thing you can do is to overlay a struct onto the shared memory:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int s_int;
    char s_str[64];
};

void* mem = mmap ...
struct MyStruct* sp = (struct MyStruct*)mem;

/* writing */
sp->s_int = 3;
strcpy(sp->s_str, "Hello");

/* reading */
printf("s_int=%d, s_str=%s\n", sp->s_int, sp->s_str);
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. That's just what I needed.